# How can I set up an idempotent producer in Spring Cloud Stream using Kafka?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I would like to take advantage of the idempotent producers introduced in Kafka 0.11. According to this [Confluent blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) a new property was added to support this:

> Idempotence: Exactly-once in order semantics per partition
>
> To turn on this feature and get exactly-once semantics per
>   partition—meaning no duplicates, no data loss, and in-order
>   semantics—configure your producer to set “enable.idempotence=true”.

The point is neither Spring Cloud Stream nor Spring Kafka document the use of that property. How can we configure it in Spring Cloud Stream applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arbitrary kafka properties can be set using `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channel>.producer.configuration`, as [documented here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_producer_properties).

So, simply set the property there.

Of course, you will need to override the default kafka binder to use the kafka11 artifact as discussed in the Ditmars release train [release notes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-starters/releases/tag/vDitmars.RELEASE).

The kafka11 binder also supports transactions.